# Scala add shutdown hook to Scala swing

Tags: swing, scala, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

I have used shutdown hooks before in java apps however not in java swing.
I want to add a shutdown hook to scala swing app. 
Scala swing has no main method so i have no idea how to implement it
I want to run a few methods just before closing so if there other ways beside the shutdown hook 
please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked inside `SwingApplication`?

https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/blob/v1.0.0-RC2/src/main/scala/scala/swing/SwingApplication.scala#L16

There is a `main` or a `startup` to register `Runtime.addShutdownHook`.

Or there is a `shutdown` template method if that's all you mean.

Comment: actually I'm using simpleSwingApplication which has the top method tp pack the frame and show it I did not even look inside swing application thank for that

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something similar to this? :

```
class MyFrame extends Frame {
  peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)

  override def closeOperation() { 
    println("Hello")
    exit(0)
  }
}
```

`Hello` will be printed when the Frame is closed.

Comment: I will try this see how it goes. i do have a question do u have to declare the the default close operation

Comment: Well, it also gets executed without it. Still the default in Java is `WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` as i remember. Guess you gotta try what works for you. `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will not result in a call to `closeOperation()`